# Open ZFS : Recently Used/Frequently Used statistics persistence

Tags: cache, zfs, statistics, persistence

ZFS cache data into ARC using two information :

- Recently Used Cache
- Frequently Used Cache

Does ZFS keep this file/metadata statistic somewhere, or does it just do with what has been used since power on?

Another way to put it: does that information persistent after a reboot (not the cache, of course, but usage statistics)?

Comment: Have a look at http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2012/01/09/activity-of-the-zfs-arc/ and `arcstat.pl`.

Answer (score 1):

currently the L2ARC does not survive a reboot on linux...

- https://www.illumos.org/issues/3525
- https://reviews.csiden.org/r/267/

but it does on Solaris...

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888471/zfs-configuration-with-ssds

Comment: thanks, my question was about ARC and not L2ARC and about file statistic that are used to fill the cache, not the cache per say. But I guess it answer my question in the sense that if L2ARC isn't persistent yet, keeping stats of volatile cache must be further on the roadmap